# How can I pass my Windows credentials in cURL?

Tags: webserver, iis, curl

I'm writing a script that uses cURL to pull data from an internal web server. I can explicitly use --user combined with --ntlm and everything works well, but I can't get it to recognize whomever's logged in and pass it transparently. If I visit the same site in Chrome/Firefox/IE it immediately gives me permissions without any prompts (We are using a proxy here if that's important). The server is using IIS.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I use (in a Windows domain environment):

```
curl --ntlm -u : ...
```

cUrl knows to supply my domain credentials and it works every time.

Comment: Thanks @BillP3rd! Just a heads up: this works perfectly when running curl within a Windows command prompt, but does not work if you are running within a terminal emulator like Cygwin on your Windows machine.

Answer (score 14):

Use `-u :` which provides an empty usercode and password, to get cURL to pick those up from the credential store.

I use this on Unix with GSSAPI and `curl -u : --negotiate ...`

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on @Phil P answer heres how I did it from my ubuntu box.

1. Find out the IP address of your domain controller instructions on how to do that [here](http://www.tecknowledgebase.com/6383/how-you-can-find-out-the-name-and-ip-address-of-the-ad-domain-controller-on-your-network/)
2. Install kerberos `sudo apt-get install krb5-user`
3. Enter the following in your `/etc/krb5.conf`

   ```
   [libdefaults]
       default_realm = YOURDOMAN
       # note that this must be in UPPER CASE
       krb4_config = /etc/krb.conf
       krb4_realms = /etc/krb.realms
       kdc_timesync = 1
       ccache_type = 4
       forwardable = true
       proxiable = true
       v4_instance_resolve = false
       v4_name_convert = {
           host = {
               rcmd = host
               ftp = ftp
           }
           plain = {
               something = something-else
           }
       }
       fcc-mit-ticketflags = true
   [realms]
       YOURDOMAN = {
           kdc = YOUR_DOAMIN_CONTROLLER_IP
       }
   [domain_realm]
       yourdomain = yourdomain
       yourdomain. = yourdomain
   ```